# How to pass value from javascript to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have JavaScript code :

```
<script>
    function ChangeRegion()
    {
        var countryId = document.getElementById("country").value;

    }
</script>
```

I have textbox on my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Register.SelectCountryId, Model.Register.Country, "Select country", new { id = "country", @class = "form-control",@onchange="ChangeRegion();" })
```

Now i need on change to pass value to my controller to get Regions

my controller:

```
 model.Register.Region = new SelectList(manager.GetRegions(model.Register.SelectCountryId), "Id", "Name");
```

**EDIT: this is my controller for post :**

when i choose country and click submit button i get values for raegions but i need to get values without submiting form

```
model.Register.Country = new SelectList(manager.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name");  
model.Register.Region = new SelectList(manager.GetRegions(model.Register.SelectCountryId), "Id", "Name");<-- i want to put here that id from javascript
model.Register.WebTypeOfLicense = new SelectList(CommonDbService.GetAllLicense(), "Id", "Name");
model.Register.City = new SelectList(manager.GetCities(model.Register.SelectRegionId), "Id", "Name");
return View(model);
```

Comment: Send the data in JSON format using AJAX, in the is case I would suggest $.getJSON();

Comment: can u post an example?

Comment: Do you want to send the value modified by JavaScript to the server through JavaScript (AJAX) or make sure it shows up when a POST/GET happens?

Comment: I have dropdown list of  Countries and Regions and main idea is when user choose Country to get regions based on what he choose in country dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using Ajax Post using your function,

This will post the value from your HTML element to the GetData action on the Home controller. Once it has reach the GetData method it will return it and show the alert on the client.

```
function ChangeRegion() {
    var countryId = document.getElementById("country").value;

    $.post('/Home/GetData', { 'CountryId': countryId }, function (d) {
        alert(d);
    }, 'json');
}
```

This code is in my HomeController,

```
public JsonResult GetData(int CountryId)
{
    return Json(CountryId);
}
```

Sorry if this isn't clear enough, if you need more direction just post some of your code, like controller & action names.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so you can use the above to return a list of regions and populate a select element. Then when you hit submit you get the value of the current selected region from the select element.